# datetimpicker custom binding knockout

Tags: knockout.js, datetimepicker

i am using datetimpicker not datepicker in my application using https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/blob/master/jquery.datetimepicker.js  i used following binding

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.datetimepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var $el = $(element);

        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $el.datetimepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            var $el = $(element);
            observable($el.datetimepicker("getDate").Value);
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $el.datetimepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            $el = $(element),
            current = $el.datetimepicker("getDate").Value;

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $el.datetimepicker("setDate", value);
            console.log("just set", $el.datetimepicker("getDate").Value);
        }
    }
};
```

but here  $el.datetimepicker("getDate") returns html element not date when i use datepicker it works fine but not with date time picker

Comment: Can you recreate this in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, to get the value of the input field you use

```
new Date($el.val())
```

instead of

```
$el.datetimepicker("getDate").Value;
```

Comment: It works but it returns plain string not date object can i use                                                                 new Date($el.val())

Comment: Yes, That should do it. I've modified the code above too.